# WebRTC: setRemoteDescription throwing error

Tags: webrtc

I have been using one of the open-source(Muaz Khan's) library for WebRTC. The following error is thrown in the following line of code :

```
peer.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(remoteSdp), cb || function() {}, function(error) {
   if (!!connection.enableLogs) {
     console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, '\t'), '\n', remoteSdp.type, remoteSdp.sdp);
   }
 });
```

Following is the error message:

```
{}
    answer v=0
    o=- 1466540501886325415 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=group:BUNDLE audio video
    a=msid-semantic: WMS
    m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 126
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:+Tp2MN9xkz9Zfn8C
    a=ice-pwd:aniPn401PK7bAWCIHV63TPhl
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 EC:BB:E4:B5:C2:6B:17:29:E4:CF:BD:8E:8A:5E:D1:BB:59:CA:8F:7D:E3:6B:CF:1D:89:DB:0B:17:AC:65:75:F4
    a=setup:active
    a=mid:audio
    b=AS:128
    a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
    a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=recvonly
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
    a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1; stereo=1; sprop-stereo=1; maxaveragebitrate=1048576; maxplaybackrate=1048576; stereo=1; sprop-stereo=1; maxaveragebitrate=1048576; maxplaybackrate=1048576
    a=maxptime:3
    a=maxptime:3
    a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
    a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
    a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
    a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
    a=maxptime:60
    m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 101 100 116 117 96 97 98
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:+Tp2MN9xkz9Zfn8C
    a=ice-pwd:aniPn401PK7bAWCIHV63TPhl
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 EC:BB:E4:B5:C2:6B:17:29:E4:CF:BD:8E:8A:5E:D1:BB:59:CA:8F:7D:E3:6B:CF:1D:89:DB:0B:17:AC:65:75:F4
    a=setup:active
    a=mid:video
    b=AS:512
    a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
    a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
    a=recvonly
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtpmap:101 VP9/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:101 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:101 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:101 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:101 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:101 transport-cc
    a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
    a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
    a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
    a=rtpmap:96 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:96 apt=100
    a=fmtp:100 x-google-min-bitrate=4194304; x-google-max-bitrate=4194304
    a=fmtp:100 x-google-min-bitrate=4194304; x-google-max-bitrate=4194304
    a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:97 apt=101
    a=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:98 apt=116
```

First of all, is the SDP valid and if it is what could possibly cause the error?

Comment: What error? I see no error message here.

Comment: The second part is whatever console.error prints, in which 'error' is empty (the first line which is {}) i.e. setRemoteDescription is throwing an error but without an error message

Comment: [You are using deprecated code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/setRemoteDescription#Deprecated_parameters), I don't know what "the open-source(Muaz Khan's) library for WebRTC" is, but I'd recommend not using it if it still uses this version of setRemoteDescription. Using WebRTC without some library is trivial in javascript anyway.

Comment: @Kevin : Thanks for pointing it out. But anyways, what are probable reasons for setRemoteDescription to fail.

Comment: Using deprecated code is usually a probable reason for failures....

Comment: I don't know how that library you use links to the underlying WebRTC code and how it fits in the browser's implementation. If, for example, your browser has implemented the new version of setRemoteDescription with the promise instead of two callbacks, you're gonna have issues if you keep using the callbacks version. I don't know if the library you use calls the proper version of setRemoteDescription and just didn't update the wrapper or if the library uses outdated code. If the latter, you're better off not using it.

Comment: If you are interested to look into the library. https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/

Comment: What browser is this? Did you try `console.error(error)` or `console.log(error.name)` ?

Comment: Chrome... console.error